# How the speed up the calculation of updating values of each element in an array based on other elements in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am now working on a calculation shown below. I want to update the values of each element based on their adjacent elements. I am now using two for loops, but it shows the calculation is very slow since there are several outer iterations. I want to know whether there is any way can speed up this calculation>

```
for i in range(1,nx+1):
    for j in range(1,ny+1):
        p[i,j]=(a*p[i-1,j]+b*p[i+1,j]+c*p[i,j-1]+d*p[i,j+1])
```

a, b, c, d are some constant, p is numpy.array type

Sample input:

```
import numpy as np
p = np.ones((5,5))
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
        p[i,j]=p[i-1,j] + p[i+1,j] +2*p[i,j+1]+2*p[i,j-1]

print(p)
```

The final output should be:

```
[[   1.    1.    1.    1.    1.]
 [   1.    6.   16.   36.    1.]
 [   1.   11.   41.  121.    1.]
 [   1.   16.   76.  276.    1.]
 [   1.    1.    1.    1.    1.]]
```

Comment: Could you add small (4,4) sample of data (a_w, p,a_e . ...)
and current results?

Comment: Try to provide sample inputs and outputs if you can, but it looks like you're performing some kind of 2D convolution, SciPy has a function that can do this. [scipy.signal.convolve2d()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html#scipy-signal-convolve2d).

Comment: I was going to suggest summing `p` offset (or sliced) in various ways.  But that calculates all values in parallel.  But in your sum the 276 depends on the previous 76, 41, 121, which in turn depend on previous values.  The only `numpy` function that approximates that kind of sequential summing is `cumsum`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment and this doesn't fully answer the question, but if you are using NumPy, you should definitely look at [array broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Hard to tell exactly what your code is doing, but using broadcasting should make it a lot easier to update the full matrix instead of value by value

Comment: I have tried to use broadcasting, but it did not give the same results. I think the problem is that each element updated will affect the following calculation.

Comment: Are you sure that reusing just calculated values is important to your math and not a side effect of implementation? It is very unusual approach for not time related data.  If so, it will be difficult to vectorize, you could try to rethink algorithm in terms of [reduceat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).

Answer (score 0):

We can at least get rid of one nested loop using `np.cumsum`. In favorable conditions (large number of columns) this can give a 30fold speedup. Sample run:

```
results equal True
original   31.644793 ms
optimized   0.861980 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 50, 600
a, b, c, d = np.random.random((4,))
P = np.random.random((n, m))

def f_OP(P):
    p = P.copy()
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        for j in range(1, m-1):
            p[i,j]=a*p[i-1,j] + b*p[i+1,j] +c*p[i,j-1]+d*p[i,j+1]
    return p

def f_pp(P):
    p = P.copy()
    pp = d*p[1:-1, 2:] + b*p[2:, 1:-1]
    pp[0] += a*p[0, 1:-1]
    pp[:, 0] += c*p[1:-1, 0]
    x = np.full((m-2,), c)
    x[0] = 1
    x = np.cumprod(x)[::-1]
    pp = np.cumsum(pp * x, axis=1)
    for i in range(1, n-2):
        pp[i] += a * np.cumsum(pp[i-1])
    p[1:-1, 1:-1] = pp / x
    return(p)

print('results equal', np.allclose(f_OP(P), f_pp(P)))

from timeit import timeit
kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=10)
print('original  {:10.6f} ms'.format(timeit('f_OP(P)', **kwds)*100))
print('optimized {:10.6f} ms'.format(timeit('f_pp(P)', **kwds)*100))
```